# not pulling Facebook JSON using App Access Tokens

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to pull JSON data from facebook using OpenGraph. This is my first time using OpenGraph and i'm finding it to be troublesome. I don't think the app is pulling data from the page because when i put the URL in the address bar i just get a JSON object that says:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I created an App Token and used it on the code below, however i cannot get it to pull up the data and it's been frustrating. I feel like I'm making something silly mistake.

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/BUFMI/feed?fields=message&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', function(data){
var posts = data.data;
var url = posts[0].id;
url = url.split("_");
url = url[1];

var postsInc = 0;
while(!posts[postsInc].hasOwnProperty('message')){
 console.log('hi');
    postsInc++;
}

//Used for posting message and breaking down String into minimal amount of characters
var message = posts[postsInc].message;
message = message.substring(0, 141);

//Turns Post into link and appends Message to Div
$('#posturl').attr('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/BUFMI/posts/' + url);
$("#fbmess").text(message);

//if longer than substring add to end of string
if(message.length > 140){
    $("#fbmess").append("...");
}
});
```

Comment: By app token you mean an actual _app access token_? That has no business being in client-side code anyway, not ever. And for what you want to achieve, you should have a look at the Facebook JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Ok, the Javascript SDK will also give me access to posts on pages? I'm attempting to pull the first post from a fan page, and i was instructed that I would do that with access tokens and OpenGraph.

Comment: Where are you using open graph? Second thing why using App access token, where did you read about this? Third- what response are you getting?